# Laravel 5.2 Eloquent - Related Model Match on One of Two Columns

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have the following tables:

```
-matches
    -id
    -user_one_id
    -user_two_id
-users
    -id
```

In my `User` model, I have the following relationship method defined:

```
public function matches(){

    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Match', 'user_one_id');

}
```

The above defines the relationship between the two tables using the `user_one_id` column on the `matches` table.

Is there a way to define the relationship so that the `matches()` method will return values where either the `user_one_id` or `user_two_id` is related to my current user?